# coredata relationship is set nil automatically

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities. (Deal, Customer)
Deal and Customer have 1:1 relationship. so Deal has customer, and Customer has deal.

first, I made Customer object named "John".
second, I made Deal object and set customer with "John" (#1 deal)
third, I made another Deal object and set customer with "John" (#2 deal)

at that time, I found some problem.
that is #1 deal's customer set nil automatically, and #2 deal's customer is "John".

how can I solve that?

ps1. I got the data from web server as JSON like this
   deals = [id: .., ..., customer: { ... }]

ps2. I update objects whenever receive data from server.

```
+ (Deal *)dealWithDealsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dic inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Deal *deal = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Deal"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deal_id = %@", [dic[@"id"] description]];

    // Execute the fetch

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Check what happened in the fetch

    if (!matches || ([matches count] > 1)) {  // nil means fetch failed; more than one impossible (unique!)
        deal = [matches lastObject];
        // handle error
    } else if (![matches count]) {
        deal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Deal" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    } else {
        deal = [matches lastObject];
    }

    deal.deal_id = [dic[@"id"] description];
    deal.deal_status = [dic[@"deal_status"] description];
    deal.deal_stage = [dic[@"deal_stage"] description];
    deal.deal_desc = [dic[@"deal_desc"] description];
    deal.localized_deal_status = [dic[@"localized_deal_status"] description];
    deal.localized_deal_stage = [dic[@"localized_deal_stage"] description];

    if (dic[@"customer"]) {
        [context performBlock:^{
            deal.customer = [Customer customerWithDictionary:dic[@"customer"] inManagedObjectContext:context];
        }];
    }

    return deal;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't have a 1:1 relationship:it is 1:N

2 deals have the same customer, so 1 customer has N deals.

CoreData wanted to keep the 1:1 constraints where 1 deal has always 1 unique customer and vice versa.

Change to one-to-many

Answer (score 2):

Make the relationship 1 to many or many to many if you want a customer to have many deals and / or many customers each to have many deals (where customers can each have the same deal).

The reference was set to nil because you said there could only be 1 reference at a time.

Comment: thanks, it was my conceptional mistake. I set Customer.deal to Customer.deals (To-Many Relationship), it solved.